# ggRadar - How to change plot line thickness and grid line thickess?

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

I've been using the ggRadar function from the ggiraphExtra package although have a couple of questions. Namely, how to change the line thickness and background gridline thickness.

I have tried changing the line thickness using geom_line but to no avail, as it doesn't interact with all lines. I have tried using theme(axis.etc) but can't interact with the gridlines (the background circles) in any way.

Here's a super simple example:

```
library(ggiraphExtra)
library(ggplot2)

data = as.data.frame(rbind(c(7,12,17,9))) 

ggRadar(data, rescale = F, size=3)+
  ylim(0,20)+
  geom_line(size=2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily modify the grid lines using `panel.gridline.major` in `theme`. Changing the thickness of the lines is somewhat harder but still possible.

```
p <- ggRadar(data, rescale = F, size = 4) +
  ylim(0,20) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 2))
plot_obj <- ggplot_build(p)
plot_obj$data[[1]]$size <- 2
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(plot_obj))
```

Original plot:
[image: original]

Modified (ugly, but proves the point).

[image: new plot]

Comment: I realise I'm commenting on my own question here, but stumbled across a solution and mentioning it just in case anyone else ever comes across this same problem, try:     `+geom_polygon(size=x)`

Answer (score 3):

I thing that you have to modify the panel.grid element like I do here to change the size:

```
 ggRadar(data, rescale = F, size=3)+
 ylim(0,20)+
 geom_line(size=1) + theme(panel.grid=element_line(size=2))
```

Comment: This works but your code has additional `+` before the additional gg layers, so it throws an error ````Error: Cannot use `+.gg()` with a single argument. Did you accidentally put `+` on a new line?````. You need to remove the `+` on the new lines as you already put `+` on the previous line

Comment: @Mr.Rlover Thanks for noticing. Answer is corrected.